# Honeywell TWF1001 Pro 3 heating 1 zone instead of coolingl

Tags: thermostat

I have a Dicon HVAC system with 3 zones. Storm light night multiple power outages.  When the AC came back on, the thermostat reset and now the heat will not shut off in zone 1, while blowing cold air in zones 2 and 3.

The complete model number of the thermostat is Honeywell TH8321WF1001 Pro 8000

Is there any setting on the thermostat I can reset? Please advise. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Are you sure you listed the complete model number?

Comment: The complete model number of the thermostat is Honeywell TH8321WF1001 Pro 8000

Comment: If this is a minisplit system with a single outside compressor/heat-exchanger, the whole system can only be in heat mode or cool mode, not both at once. I don't understand the rules for resolving a conflict and deciding which mode to actually respond to, but more than once I've had to go around the house looking for the one indoor unit which was still set for the other season. Are you *sure* you are getting both heating and cooling at the same time, or is one unit just not cooling and allowing the house to warm up?

Answer (score 1):

My Mitsubishi gets upset by power dropouts.  This works, maybe it will work with this one.

- Find the override switch next to the outside unit.
- Flip it off
- Wait a good 30 seconds to a minute
- and then turn it on.

Otherwise, it may be damaged.

Comment: I flipped the breaker off this morning and waited 5 min and turned back on. Should I still go outside? The ac unit outside is connected to a power surge box.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

According to the honeywell web site, the total reset procedure is as follows:

VisionPRO TH8321WF
PERFORM FACTORY RESET:

Press Menu

Go to Dealer Information

Scroll to the bottom and write down the date code

Press Done

Scroll down to Installer Options

Enter the date code.

Select Reset to Defaults.

Select Yes

Congratulations! You’ve reset your device! You can now configure your device for its new settings via the thermostat screen.

https://www.honeywellhome.com/us/en/support/how-do-i-reset-my-honeywell-home-device/

There is also a procedure for the pro 8000 listed:

VisionPRO 8000 (TH8320WF, RTH8580WF)

PERFORM FACTORY RESET

Press System

Press and hold the blank box in the center

Change the number on the left to 0710, and the number on the right to 1

Press Done

Congratulations! You’ve reset your device! You can now configure your device for its new settings via the thermostat screen.

Comment: Hi Jack! I followed your steps however, there is no date code. It's blank.

Comment: @user168475  I added the procedure for the pro 8000  which was also in the link provided.  try it.

Comment: Will do. Thank you!